# BigQuery Covertion of Invalid Datetime format (M/D/YYYY) with AM/PM?

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, format, date-format

I am working with data in a different date format, and when trying to CAST it as DATETIME, i get the following error :

Invalid datetime string "5/6/2019 1:46:00 PM"

The date is formatted as MM/DD/YYYY, and i can read that it must be YYYY/MM/DD in order for DATETIME to work.
I was wondering if there were an easy approach to change the format?

Thanks in advance.

I have tried the FORMAT_DATE() function with "%Y%M%D%P as the new format and

```
PARSE_DATETIME("%m/%d/%Y% %I:%M:%S %P" , '5/6/2019 1:46:00 PM')
```

However the date is still not compatible with this date format.

Comment: would you try `%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p`  ?

Answer (score 0):

As @Jaytiger mentions, I should've used the format : %m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p instead.